# How to remove brackets from python string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I know from the title you might think that this is a duplicate but it's not.

```
for id,row in enumerate(rows):
    columns = row.findall("td")

    teamName = columns[0].find("a").text, # Lag
    playedGames = columns[1].text, # S
    wins = columns[2].text,
    draw = columns[3].text,
    lost = columns[4].text,
    dif = columns[6].text, # GM-IM
    points = columns[7].text, # P - last column

    dict[divisionName].update({id :{"teamName":teamName, "playedGames":playedGames, "wins":wins, "draw":draw, "lost":lost, "dif":dif, "points":points }})
```

This is how my Python code looks like. Most of the code is removed but essentially i am extracting some information from a website. And i am saving the information as a dictionary. When i print the dictionary every value has a bracket around them ["blbal"] which causes trouble in my Iphone application. I know that i can convert the variables to strings but i want to know if there is a way to get the information DIRECTLY as a string.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That looks like you have a string inside a list:

```
["blbal"]
```

To get the string just index  `l = ["blbal"]` `print(l[0]) -> "blbal"`.

If it is a string use `str.strip` `'["blbal"]'.strip("[]")` or slicing `'["blbal"]'[1:-1]` if they are always present.

Comment: you probably meant '"[blbal]".strip...'

Comment: @frnhr, the OP's code seems to have quotes around the inner string, not totally sure what it is exactly but I added single quotes so the OP can use it as an example.

Comment: using string = string[0] worked however that means i would need to add 7 rows like that which i dont like. As my original question where if there was a way to get the it in that format at the first stage meaning from this stage wins = collumns[2].text,

Comment: If you want all the contents in a single string use `" ".join(your_list)`

Comment: im sorry i dont know what " " is supposed to be?

Comment: @hamzah that means each subelement in the list will be separated by an empty string `",".join(your_list)` would separate every subelement by a comma etc..

Answer (score 3):

you can also you `replace` to just replace the text/symbol that you don't want with the empty string.

```
text = ["blbal","test"]
strippedText = str(text).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','').replace('\"','')
print(strippedText)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
text = "some (string) [another string] in brackets"
re.sub("\(.*?\)", "", text)
# some in brackets
# works for () and will work for [] if you replace () with [].
```

The `\(.*?\)` format matches brackets with some text in them with an unspecified length. And the `\[.*?\]` format matches also but a square brackets with some text inside the brackets.

The output will not contain brackets and texts inside of them.

If you want to match only square brackets replace square brackets with the bracket of choice and vise versa.

To match `()` and `[]` bracket in one go, use this format `(\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]:)` joining two pattern with the `|` character.

Comment: You can't prevent `.*?` from matching anything at all. Your regex will match whatever is between the first `(` and the first `)` after it.